# Can I close firefox browser tab or firefox browser from ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line

I dont want to kill browser process, I just want to shut down the browser from command.

Comment: From the Ubuntu terminal you can't close the tabs of Firefox, but you could close the tabs of Chrome browser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Option 1. wmctrl

*wmctrl can query the window manager for information, and it can request that certain window management actions be taken.* ([wmctrl manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html))

For closing firefox gracefully, wmctrl could do the trick--

```
wmctrl -c "Firefox" -x "Navigator.Firefox"
```

you may need to install it first with

```
sudo apt install wmctrl
```

### Caveat #1

`wmctrl -c` only closes one window at a time. If you have multiple firefox windows open, you will need to run `wmctrl -c` multiple times.

#### Example Solution

```
while wmctrl -c 'Firefox' -x 'Firefox.Navigator'; do sleep 0.1; done
```

### Caveat #2

[image: Close tabs? confirmation window prompt]

If `browser.tabs.warnOnClose` is set to true, Firefox will prevent the window from closing. This can be changed in `about:config`, but that is a compromise to your Firefox user experience which may not be worth the risk.

## Option 2. xdotool

*xdotool lets you programatically (or manually) simulate keyboard input and mouse activity, move and resize windows, etc.* ([xdotool man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/xdotool.1.html))

[ZyMOS](https://superuser.com/users/418738/zymos) was the first to suggest this [solution](https://superuser.com/a/877686/217278). I'm simply building on their answer by adding additional logic to handle the possible appearance of the close confirmation window.

### Example Script

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
#
# TITLE: close-firefox.sh
#
# DESCRIPTION: Programmatically closes firefox in a way 
#              similar to how a human closes firefox.


# Find the window ID of a Firefox window.
FFWID=$(xdotool search --name "Mozilla Firefox" | head -1)

# use the Firefox window ID to activate that window
xdotool windowactivate --sync $FFWID

# Send the "Quit" hotkey "Ctrl + q" to Firefox.
# https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly
xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+q

# Give the system a moment to process
sleep 0.1

# Find the window ID of the Firefox close confirmation window
CWID=$(xdotool search --name "close tabs")

# End the script if xdotool didn't detect a confirmation window
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# Activate the Confirmation window
xdotool windowactivate --sync $CWID

# Send an "Return" key press to the confirmation window.
# This does the default action of pressing the "Close tabs" button.
xdotool key --clearmodifiers Return
```

Comment: it doesn't really work. It *closes* window, but doesn't quit app. That's different things.

Comment: I only suggested SIGTERM because closing the window wasn't sufficient for you. I didn't know you wanted graceful. But please see my updated answer for graceful.

Comment: Don't wag — "Quit" is always graceful. Updated answer isn't suggesting anything useful.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot close a tab, but you can close the browser using one of these:

```
pkill firefox
killall firefox
```

Comment: Actually i dont want to kill process. I want close it normally then next time firefox open normally without restore option.

Comment: ‘kill‘ by default terminates (sigterm) a process; one has to specify "-9" to "kill" the process. The sigterm signal can be caught by a running process and handled gracefully (depending on the program implementation); the sigkill signal can't be caught & is the "ungraceful" exit that often requires program "recovery" at startup.

Answer (score 4):

If you wish to "entirely" close Firefox "gracefully", try using xdotool.  By gracefully, i mean closing the program, not killing it.  By entirely, i mean "quiting" Firefox, closing all windows, all at once.  wmctrl will gracefully close a single Firefox window, but will not close all windows.

Create the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

WID=`xdotool search "Mozilla Firefox" | head -1`
xdotool windowactivate --sync $WID
xdotool key --clearmodifiers ctrl+q
```

That should do it.